# Problem of research on a cast object with eloquent using elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, eloquent, laravel-scout

In fact I have a problem with elasticsearch using eloquent. I don't know how to search from an object. The object is casted as an array in my model, then I use the nested type of elasticsearch. The index, the mapping, the import everything works, but I don't get a result. Can you help me please. I use scout-elasticsearch-driver.

Here is my mapping:

```
/**
* @var array
*/
protected $mapping = [
    'properties' => [
        'skills' => [
            "type" => "nested",
        ],
    ]
];
```

Here is my cast:

```
protected $casts = [
    'skills' => 'array',
];
```

Here is an example:

```
$job = $job->search($keywords);
$job = $job->whereIn('skills', ['{"text":"PHP","tiClasses":["ti-valid"]}']);
$job->paginate(20);
```

The real value if I'm not mistaken is `[{"text": "PHP", "tiClasses": ["ti-valid"]}]`.
An array containing one or more objects.

Can you help me please.
Thanks

Comment: whose/what package?

Comment: I think https://github.com/crowdfavorite/scout-nested-elasticsearch-engine might do what you need

Comment: I use https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver, it's much more professional than what you show me.